# How to list all pdf files under a directory and under sub directories under that directory

Tags: unix

I have a directory called `MainDir` under which there are five sub directories named `OneDir`, `TwoDir`, `ThreeDir`, `FourDir` and `FiveDir`.

Along with files of other types, all the six directories contain some pdf files.

I want to do some processing on these pdf files through my java program which I am calling in a unix script.

The input to my java program is a single pdf file name.

```
java MyProgram $pdfFileName
```

How can I correctly create a loop in my script which lists all the pdf files in the six directories and passes them to variable `pdfFileName` one by one inside the loop ?

Thanks for Reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find -exec` as shown below:

```
find MainDir -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec java MainClass {} \;
```

If you must use `xargs`, you should use `-n 1` because you say your java application only accepts one file at a time:

```
find MainDir -type f -name "*.pdf" | xargs -n 1 java MainClass
```

Comment: What if my java command is like: java -DLOG_DIR=$LOG_DIR -Dlog4j.configuration=file://$CONFIG_DIR/myLog4j.log4j.properties -classpath $CLASSPATH org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner job_config.xml myJob dataDirPath=$DATA_DIR/ outputdataDirPath=$DATA_DIR/ logDirPath=$LOG_DIR/   with several more arguments. In this case how would find -exec look like ?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it is long. Simply put the whole thing after `-exec`. e.g. `find ... -exec java -DLOG_DIR=$LOG_DIR -Dlog4j.configuration=file://$CONFIG_DIR/myLog4j.log4j.properties -classpath $CLASSPATH... {} \;`